# How to set a value to an attribute with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    onclick="ToggleAllItems(event,this,12)" 
    title="Select or deselect all items" 
    class="s4-selectAllCbx"
>
```

How can I set `var i = 15` to the `onclick` attribute instead of `12`?

It should be changed after the PageLoad.

Comment: What task are you trying to complete by doing this? There may be an easier way than mucking around with the value of an `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Could you show the `ToggleAllItems` code.

Comment: **@ajp15243**: I need to split the onclick away and then add it again to my code. However, the "12" is not a solid number, I need to set "15" or another number to this.

Comment: **@dbh**: It calls a js file which has a large amount of code. As a result, I do not want to change anything from that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED TO FIX MISTAKE**

In Jquery you can try this:

```
$("#id").attr("onclick","ToggleAllItems(event,this," + i + ")");
```

It would take the onclick attribute and rewrite its value, so you can change the third parameter to *i*.

**Note:**

You would have to make sure this attr change happens before the onclick event executes.

Comment: change `onclick="ToggleAllItems(event,this,12)"` to `onclick="ToggleAllItems(event,this,15)"`. I just want to make sure that this has been changed before the onclick event executes.

Comment: Place my code into $(document).ready(function() { "CODE GOES HERE" }); 
document ready runs on page load. Change i in my code to whatever you want the number to be, e.g 15

Comment: That's great. I have tried it but the i was i, it wasn't as anything I expected. `var i = number` (number here can be 15,20,25,30...)

Comment: place the var i = number as the first line in the document.ready function

Comment: It doesn't work with `i` in `ToggleAllItems(event,this,i)`. It still got `i` and didn't change to any number... Is it correct? if I change little bit of the code such as ``ToggleAllItems(event,this,'' + i)``

Comment: Oh sorry. Mental blank.... $("#id").attr("onclick","ToggleAllItems(event,this," + i + ")");

Comment: That will open the string add the value of i to the string, and then close it again.

Answer (score 1):

Why not removing the onclick property and adding yours... [LIKE THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y3MKL/)

```
$('.s4-selectAllCbx').prop('onclick', '');
$('.s4-selectAllCbx').on('click', function (event) {
    ToggleAllItems(event, this, 15)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. However, it should be changed before the onclick event executes.

Comment: So you can't do all of when the page loads? Remove the current onclick and add yours?

Comment: **@vyx.ca**: When the page loads, I can extract "15" from another attribute and then Can I add the number to the onclick event before it executes?

Comment: **@vyx.ca**: What do you mean here?

Comment: That was what I was saying. When the page loads, you replace all the current onclick events with the information you want. This will happen before the user clicks on the button so the initial code will not run, only the new one you created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question. Please don't use `onclick` attribute if you will to put data.

```
$("#yourinputid").click(function(e) {
    var event = e;
    var element = this; // your "this" will be element.
    var i = 15;

    //paste you ToggleAllItems() code here.
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but the ToggleAllItems() was a function of SharePoint. Therefore, I am attempting to split it away and try to add it again in order to make sure that it runs as it's own SharePoint's function.

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing here. What if,

$("#yourinputid").click(function(e) {
var i = 15;
    ToggleAllItems(e,this,i)
});

Comment: As a quick glance, does it run after the executing of the checkbox's onclick event?

Comment: Thank you. Yet what I need here is it is automatically changed after the PageLoad. When I use the onclick event that runs another function.

Comment: So you want to change the element's 'onclick' property? or you just want to change the 12 to 15?

Comment: Just change 12 to 15 after PageLoad runs.